# COM file starting point

Tags: x86, decompilation, dos-com

I'm having issue reversing a small old COM file from the early 90s.  My understanding was that code begins at 0x100, however the one I have seems to begin at 0x90 (0s before).  However some of the commands point to locations well outside the program space and I'm wondering if the offset isn't wrong - particularly after c2.

Using onlinedisassembler.com, I have a few example segments below...

```
.data:0x00000090    e612    out    0x12,al  
.data:0x00000092    131c16  adc    ebx,DWORD PTR [esi+edx*1]    
.data:0x00000095    d89ade3b6153    fcomp  DWORD PTR [edx+0x53613bde]   
.data:0x0000009b    3831    cmp    BYTE PTR [ecx],dh    
.data:0x0000009f    d309    ror    DWORD PTR [ecx],cl   
.data:0x000000a1    41  inc    ecx  
.data:0x000000a2    56  push   esi  
.data:0x000000a3    5b  pop    ebx  
.data:0x000000a4    ce  into
```

...

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to look like valid code at all. I'm 99% sure it's something else, not processor instructions. Is that a COM object or a .com file? As you're saying "code begins at 0x100", i assume the 2nd. The space from 0x80 to 0xff was reserved for the command line, and wasn't initialized after the trailing '\0', so what you're seeing is probably just random garbage.

Comment: This is a .com file.  I agree that it's supposed to begin at 0x100, so I'm very confused.  If I look at what starts at 0x100, I get this:
>    .data:0x00000000 2453 and    al,0x53
>    .data:0x00000002 52 push   edx
    .data:0x00000003 4e dec    esi
    .data:0x00000004 59 pop    ecx
    .data:0x00000005 a0b2e0212f mov   al,ds:0x2f21e0b2
    .data:0x0000000a 18f5 sbb    ch,dh
    .data:0x0000000c f3f3f9 repz repz stc
    .data:0x0000000f 7d9b jge    0xffffffac
    .data:0x00000011 5d pop    ebp
    .data:0x00000012 224adb and    cl,BYTE PTR [edx-0x25] 
    .data:0x00000015 b013 mov    al,0x13

Comment: Are you sure these are executable files? Can you actually run them (in DOS)?

Comment: it seems oda silently ate 0f 25 between 9b and 9f 0f 25 iirc is an invalid opcode #ud exception should be generated can be some ntvdm detection not sure i had seen 0f 3f in vpc not generating exception but silently executing while most disassemblers couldnt decipher it

Answer (score 4):

The DOS .COM files get loaded into the **memory** at offset 100h (the first 100h bytes are the [PSP](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/371-psp__program_segment_prefix.html), allocated and filled by the DOS loader). The file on disk of course starts at byte 0 (which corresponds to address 100h in memory).

Since .COM is just a binary blob with no headers, your disassembler has no idea about the address or even the processor mode it's using. That why you get garbage output.

To get correct results you need to ensure you're disassembling *in 16-bit mode*. On onlinedisassembler.com, this is the "i8086" option (which actually comes from binutils on which it's obviously based).

However, the bytes you quote don't make sense even in 16-bit mode so it's possible the file has been compressed or encrypted. Since you did not quote the beginning of the file, we can only guess.

Comment: The bytes you see in my post at 0x90 are the first non zero bytes.  Everything before that is 00.

Comment: Using i8086 from 0x100, I still don't understand (then again my assembly is rusty)

`    0x00 2453 and   $0x53,%al  
`    0x02 52 push  %dx  
`    0x03 4e dec   %si  
`    0x04 59 pop   %cx  
`    0x05 a0b2e0 mov   0xe0b2,%al  
`    0x08 212f and   %bp,(%bx)  
`    0x0a 18f5 sbb   %dh,%ch  
`    0x0c f3f3f9 repz repz stc  
`    0x0f 7d9b jge   0xffffffac  
`    0x11 5d pop   %bp  
`    0x12 224adb and   -0x25(%bp,%si),%cl  
`    0x15 b013 mov   $0x13,%al  
`    0x17 fb sti  
`    0x18 e510 in    $0x10,%ax  
`    0x1b 33e2 xor   %dx,%sp  
`    0x1d 55 push  %bp  
`    0x1e 0411 add   $0x11,%al

Comment: Why doesn't code markup work in comments??!  So frustrating!

Comment: Just add a plain hexdump to your post, don't try to disassemble it. So far it seems your file may be not a com file at all.

Comment: tx igor for i8086 i played with addr16 and data16 with i386 didnt make any sense  thought oda didnt disassemble 16bit plucked the bytes and dropped it into debug.com didnt make sense either with 
:\>awk "{print $2}" copypaste.txt | tr -d \n\r | xxd -r -p > some.com :\>debug some.com
-u 100
14F3:0100 E612          OUT     12,AL
14F3:0102 131C          ADC     BX,[SI]
14F3:0104 16            PUSH    SS
14F3:0105 D89ADE3B              FCOMP   DWORD PTR [BP+SI+3BDE]
14F3:0109 61            DB      61
14F3:010A 53            PUSH    BX
14F3:010B 3831          CMP     [BX+DI],DH

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and added the raw bytes of the two .COM files I have.  I hope someone can provide insight where I have failed all weekend.

Comment: What Igor said!  If those file dumps are accurate then you do not have a DOS-executible COM file.

Comment: reason:- as Igor says, execution of a COM file begins at the first byte (after loading to 0x0100).  Your first bytes are nulls, indicating something quite different from what you assumed.